# How to ask for permissions with Google+ Badge API?

Tags: api, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I am using Google+ Badge API to get Followers and +1's. Also, i have the Signin button using the Google+ Signin API. When i login using the Signin button, it asks for the email permission. But, when i want to Follow or +1 the Google+ Page it asks me to login and never asks for the permissions.

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title>Demo: Getting an email address using the Google+ Sign-in button</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .hide { display: none;}
  .show { display: block;}
  </style>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /*
   * Triggered when the user accepts the the sign in, cancels, or closes the
   * authorization dialog.
   */
  function loginFinishedCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
      if (authResult['error'] == undefined){
        gapi.auth.setToken(authResult); // Store the returned token.
        toggleElement('signin-button'); // Hide the sign-in button after successfully signing in the user.
        getEmail();                     // Trigger request to get the email address.
      } else {
        console.log('An error occurred');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Empty authResult');  // Something went wrong
    }
  }

  /*
   * Initiates the request to the userinfo endpoint to get the user's email
   * address. This function relies on the gapi.auth.setToken containing a valid
   * OAuth access token.
   *
   * When the request completes, the getEmailCallback is triggered and passed
   * the result of the request.
   */
  function getEmail(){
    // Load the oauth2 libraries to enable the userinfo methods.
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
          var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
          request.execute(getEmailCallback);
        });


    // This sample assumes a client object has been created.
    // To learn more about creating a client, check out the starter:
    //  https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript
    gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
     var request = gapi.client.plus.people.list({
       'userId': 'me',
       'collection': 'visible'
     });
     request.execute(function(resp) {
       console.log('Num people visible:' + resp.totalItems);
     });
    });

    // This sample assumes a client object has been created.
    // To learn more about creating a client, check out the starter:
    //  https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript
    gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
     var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
       'userId': 'me'
     });
     request.execute(function(resp) {
       console.log('Retrieved profile for:' + resp.displayName);
       console.log(resp);
     });
    });
   }




  function getEmailCallback(obj){
    var el = document.getElementById('email');
    var email = '';

    if (obj['email']) {
      email = 'Email: ' + obj['email'];
    }

    //console.log(obj);   // Uncomment to inspect the full object.

    el.innerHTML = email;
    toggleElement('email');
  }

  function toggleElement(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el.getAttribute('class') == 'hide') {
      el.setAttribute('class', 'show');
    } else {
      el.setAttribute('class', 'hide');
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="signin-button" class="show">
     <div class="g-signin" data-callback="loginFinishedCallback"
      data-clientid="MY_CLIENT_ID"
      data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
      data-height="short"
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
      >
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Place this tag where you want the badge to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-width="210" data-href="//plus.google.com/MY_PAGE_ID" data-rel="publisher" data-theme="dark"></div>
  <div id="email" class="hide"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way around where i can ask users for permissions when they login using the Follow AND +1 button?

Also, if a user has set his/her profile fields (like birthday) privacy to 'ONLY ME', then can i request for those fields? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

1- there isn't a Badges API.

2- You should distinguish between 
- using Google functionality, like the badges or the +1 button, which requires the user to login to Google+
- using your service's functionality, like the sign-in button, which requires the user to connect their Google+ account to your service

In short the user has to sign-in to Google+ (which doesn't require any permissions because Google+ is the identity provider) and *connect* to your service/site/app which requires them to give you permission.

Comment: 1 - yes there is a Google+ Badge API. Here you go - https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/

2 - i think u din't get my question brother! i want to get the permissions from the user when they click on "follow" or "+1". Now, i can only achieve it through "Sign in" button

Comment: You're right that we have a Javascript API for rendering badges: https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/#jsapi 

None of those badges have callbacks that would let you trigger action when the user clicks on them.

The +1 button does have a callback that can cause your function to be invoked: https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/

I advise against it but you can set up your own callback on a parent element and have it trigger the sign-in flow. You'd effectively be hacking the custom rendering functionality: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#customizing_the_sign-in_button